# Get file path by file name from documents directory ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

In my application I download PDF files which gets stored in "Document" directory under different sub folders.

Now I have file name for which I want to get its path in "Document" directory but problem is I don't know the exact sub folder under which that file is stored.

So is there any method which will give me **file path by file's name** like there is one method which works for main bundle:

```
(NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension
```

I don't want to iterate through each folder which is a tedious way.

Thanks.

Comment: See Abhi's answer. Programming often involves writing lots of detail-oriented code, but in this isn't a ton of code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can search the documents directory like this:

```
NSString *searchFilename = @"hello.pdf"; // name of the PDF you are searching for

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

NSString *documentsSubpath;
while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
  if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
    continue;
  }

  NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
}
```

EDIT:

You can also use NSPredicate. If there are many thousands of files in the documents directory, this might crash with an out of memory error.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.lastPathComponent == %@", searchFilename];
NSArray *matchingPaths = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:documentsDirectory] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", matchingPaths);
```

Comment: thanx, it seems that there is no alternative to search for all possible paths.

Comment: @ViruMax there are alternatives. For example you could grab every subpath (file manager has a `supbathsAtPath:` method) and then filter the returned array using a predicate (`@"self.lastPathComponent == %@", searchFilename`. But honestly it's better to just enumerate all the directories. It's not that much code.

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of NSPredicate.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2 pretty simple:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
let plistPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("someFile.plist")
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem given in the question, what if there are many subfolders under document directory, this logic won't work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to walk the tree to find the file; there's no equivalent to -pathForResource:ofType that works in the ~/Documents directory.

Comment: means will have to try for all possible paths