# share an audio file on whatsapp which is stored in document directory of ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

Well I have tried different ways to share an audio file to whatsapp (audio is stored in my application's document directory) from iPhone, but i am not able to send any audios using those ways, instead of sharing the file the application crashes with the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

and this is the code which causes this error

```
NSString *savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]      pathForResource:fileToShare ofType:@"caf"];

_documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
```

I am just 2 Weeks into iOS programming so please just aviod any blunder made by me!
Thanks!

Comment: if you have stored audio in documentDirectory then you have to give path for document directory. you are passing bundle path so audio is not found in  you bundle. check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780928/get-file-path-by-file-name-from-documents-directory-ios). Hope you know document directory and bundle difference.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani i do not know how to do that if you can give me some example that would be great :)

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani ok let me check that lick than i will ask you further questions